# Express session store: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection on _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using sessionstore npm module to store the session data in the database.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionstore = require('sessionstore');

app.use(session({
  secret:appConfig.JWT_SECRET,
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  store: sessionstore.createSessionStore({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      dbName: 'MyDatabase',
      collectionName: 'sessions',
      timeout: 10000
  }),
  cookie: {
         maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 // Milliseconds (3600000ms -> 60min)
     }
}));
```

and i am getting this error :

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myDatabase.sessions index: _id_ dup key: { : "Lz4SJIHaBfGFfNg3_ChNTkFnwKBLQDUN" }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/user/public_html/projectName/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/home/user/public_html/projectName/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:139:22)
    at /home/user/public_html/projectName/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1060:67
    at /home/user/public_html/projectName/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:461:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

How to prevent creating documents with the same id. Also i am not using Mongoose in my project. What can be done as this does not crash the server but close down all the connections with the database and the users are not able to login (or there is no api response).

I also check some similar questions on SO as well as github but they all point towards mongoose or change in field name but there is no such thing in my case.

Please help.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Have you tried setting another field to use for the key other than `_id`? Note you will need to clear the contents of the collection before changing anything.

Comment: Does `db.sessions.drop()` work? (from this, old issue: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/issues/78 )

Comment: I am not adding any other key. I am saving username and email address is data object

Comment: @Lissy Is dropping the collection a permanent solution ? I havent changes my fields stored in the session from last 6 months. i am getting this error now only

Comment: @AmanGupta The OP does not know. They are just better at using a search engine than you are. If you read the issue though you generally should be specifying a different document property as the `id` parameter to the session store configuration. And you should be prepared to drop the collection. Like I said, there appears to be a bug where it is trying to "create" with an existing session key. So dropping the data and indexes removes any duplicates. Sessions really should not be considered "long term persistent". if you need that, then encourage users to create accounts instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Dropping the sessions collection did not solved the problem.

Comment: @AmanGupta Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Arjan No still struggling with the same problem. just clearing the sessions collection everytime this occurs.